# PostgreSQL user/role restricted to views only?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I need to grant customer access to a set of 'views' in my database. I have it working so that the user/role can SELECT against the desired views and not any tables. However, the user/role can still browse the schema and see the tables and table's columns and datatypes, etc. Is there a way to prevent this? So that if a user/role accesses the database with PgAdmin III or psql or something similar, that they only 'see' the authorized views and nothing else?

Comment: So what's the problem? They still won't be able to select from the tables.

Comment: We don't want them to be able to see the actual tables. There are IP and security considerations.

Comment: Why security? If they can't select from the tables there is nothing they can do with the information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'm not sure if you're trying to bait me, but can you just take my word for it that the reasons exist and are valid?

Comment: I do understand that you think there is a reason. I'm challenging the reason because I don't think it will give you any additional security. Search the Postgres mailing list. This is being asked on a regular basis there.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name We have contractors that we do not want to expose our schema to for reasons of protecting the intellectual property associated with our application. There is a lot to be learned from our table structures as to how we do what we do that we don't want competitors getting.

Comment: pgAdmin doesn't work when it doesn't have access to the information_schema or pg_catalog. Tables and views are both stored in pg_catalog, to show the availability of a view, pgAdmin has to read pg_class in pg_catalog. Use other software if they are only allowed to see the data and not the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid duplicating all data in materialized views ..

You could set up another database - in a *different cluster*, so it does not share the same catalog. This can even be on a different machine.

- Access the views in your prime database via [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html).
- Only allow access via dblink to prime db for a defined user the customer *cannot* access.
- Create table functions accessing the data on the prime server.
- Provide views selecting from these table functions and allow your customers user to `SELECT`.

Now they have no access whatsoever to the base tables.

Comment: This is very intriguing. Thank you. I am researching this. I may have further questions if that is OK. The four bullets above are not very clear to me as to how this all works.

Answer (score 1):

The only option that comes to mind if you want contractors to access the views without being able to see the structure of the tables from which the views draw their data is to *materialize* the views into actual tables (vie `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...`) dump those, and restore them to a database which your untrusted contractors can access.

Presumably your application will be a web application or some such which won't put database login data within reach of users; otherwise you have much bigger problems than this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can prevent a contractor from looking at the types.  The problem is that these are in the same system tables, and I am very afraid of what will happen if you revoke permissions to those.  In essence I suspect that nothing will work.

PostgreSQL does not have the concept of restricting access to type definitions.

You can prevent them from selecting data from the tables however by just restricting the select access on the tables.  Views run under the local permission of the user who defined them.  You can REVOKE on the underlying tables and leave them with access to the data in the views.  But you can't prevent them from seeing the type definitions of the underlying tables.

Put another, more object-oriented way, you cannot safely permit users in PostgreSQL from looking at your class definitions.  You can prevent them from looking at the actual objects however.

Edit:  The only system catalogs I know of that are restricted in this way are those which include encrypted passwords.  Most system catalogs are relatively open and a lot of code requires having permission to these.  Given the object-behavior of PostgreSQL I don't think you can restrict access to either function definitions (in compiled environments, that's not source code though but would include which shared object files the routines are in), or type definitions (and that includes table structures).

Edit2:  Actually there is a single, good answer, and that is to not give the contractors access to the database through direct tools like psql and require instead that they go through some middleware you control.  Then you can have complete access to what they can see or not.  For example, you could modify phppgadmin to refuse to show anything in the pg_catalog schema if you wanted.  This is hack-the-tool territory though and you do not want to be futzing around with system table permissions.